# Logging. Missing method 'WriteWarning' exception

Tags: c#, exception, logging, asp.net-core

I have created new ASP.NET vNext Project and add the following to Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        // Add cookie-based authentication to the request pipeline
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType; 
            o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseWelcomePage();

        app.UseIdentity();
    }
```

and to project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Client": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta1",

    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta1",

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
},
```

On start I receive the following exception

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Framework.Logging.LoggerExtensions.WriteWarning(Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILogger, System.String)'.
at Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>.Start<TStateMachine>(TStateMachine& stateMachine) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync() 
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore<T>(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory) 
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware<TOptions>.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.KlrHttpApplication.<ProcessRequestAsyncImpl>d__1.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.<InvokeProcessRequestAsyncImpl>d__1.MoveNext()N
```

From other side, next line does not raise exception: 
    loggerFactory.Create("TestLogger").WriteWarning("some warning msg");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer the specific question**

Your issue seems to stem from the fact that you are mixing versions of dependencies, and for prerelease dependencies there is no compatibility bar. You basically have to use the same version across the board.

I think things start from this line:

```
 "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
```

What it means is that you are asking for the latest nuget package available, and depending on your nuget source (please share your nuget.config) it might mean that you are getting a much newer version of this package than the other packages that are marked beta1

For example:

```
 "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta1",
```

Try to mark the packages as 1.0.0-beta1 instead.

**On another note**

The order of calling middlewares is important, it determines the execution order of the pipeline. In your case you added identity after MVC, you want to move that line up above AddMvc.